# Imprimir automáticamente cada vez que se cree un archivo en una carpeta - Python

Tags: python, netbeans, archivo, loops, consola

Soy nuevo ocupando el lenguaje Python y tengo un problema.
El código continuación muestra el nombre y el contenido del ultimo archivo creado en una carpeta en especifico:

```
import glob

import os   

 newest=max(glob.iglob('/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'), key=os.path.getctime)

 print newest

 file = open(newest,'r')

 texto = [x.strip() for x in file.readlines()]

 print texto
```

Output

```
/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela\Ultimo archivo creado.txt
['Contenido del ultimo archivo creado']
```

El problema es que quiero que el código se mantenga ejecutando constantemente con el fin de que cada vez que cree un archivo en la carpeta se muestre su nombre y su contenido de forma automática sin tener que volverlo a ejecutar
¿Tengo que agregar un while y un break?

Comment: Yo si probaría con while y break, pero ten en cuenta que en cuanto encuentre archivo saldrá el programa si pones el break, si no lo pones se quedará ejecutando todo el rato y tendrás que pararlo de alguna otra forma.

Comment: Usa un while infinito y `time.sleep` para que vaya haciendo la comprobación cada x tiempo determinado (1h, 1dia,...). Por otra parte, si estás empezando con Python te recomiendo encarecidamente que uses Python 3. En tu código solo tienes que adaptar los `print`s. Python2 ya no se va a actualizar más y dejará de recibir parches en 2020 (pasado mañana). Si empiezas ahora con Python no debe ser ningún problema usar Python3.

Comment: Añadí el import time y las etiquetas while True: y  time.sleep (30) y me resulto . Pero como la hago para que deje de mostrar el mismo resultado? o sea, que deje de imprimir si el archivo y el contenido siguen igual y que solo imprima si se añadió un nuevo documento en la carpeta.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta, si no la entendí mal es: quiero controlar constantemente una carpeta y si hay nuevos archivos imprimirlos. Esto tiene varias dificultades para resolver.

Por empezar, la idea es resolver todo con código básico, pero te comento que hay módulos de python especialmente creados para esto, por ejemplo [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog).

El primer problema es obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo, lamentablemente el uso de `os.path.getctime` no es multiplataforma, por lo que vamos a incorporar el código de [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) enlace a la solución para que el script nos sirva en Linux/Windows.

Como ya te comentaron, necesitas un ciclo infinito `while True`, que igual se puede interrumpir con un `ctrl-c`. En ese ciclo invocaremos a una rutina `get_newestfiles` que se encargará de devolver una lista de los archivos cuya fecha de creación sea superior a una determinada que le pasaremos por parámetro, debe ser una lista por que no sabes si entre cada verificación no se ha creado más de un archivo (y entiendo que los quieres imprimir todos). La idea es que luego de invocar esta rutina, tenemos que guardarnos en una variable, la fecha máxima de creación de los archivos devueltos, y la siguiente verificación la haremos de los archivos posteriores a esa fecha.

Aclaraciones:

- No es necesario convertir las fechas a otro formato, al estar en UTC (los segundos desde el 1/1/1970) nos sirven para hacer las comparaciones. Si tenemos que mostrarlas habrá que convertirlas.
- Como bien comenta [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) enlace, hay una imposibilidad de obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo en Linux, lo que hace la rutina `creation_date` en el caso de Linux, es devolver la fecha de modificación.
- No agregué la impresión del archivo, eso en teoría, no es tan simple como parece ya que eventualmente podría estar bloqueado por el proceso que lo genera, en cuyo caso hay que hacer otro ciclo intentando abrir de modo exclusivo el archivo y cuando esto sea posible recién ahí mandarlo a imprimir.

Código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import platform 
from time import sleep
from operator import itemgetter

def creation_date(path_to_file):
    """
    Try to get the date that a file was created, falling back to when it was
    last modified if that isn't possible.
    See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/1709587 for explanation.
    """
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return os.path.getctime(path_to_file)
    else:
        stat = os.stat(path_to_file)
        try:
            return stat.st_birthtime
        except AttributeError:
            # We're probably on Linux. No easy way to get creation dates here,
            # so we'll settle for when its content was last modified.
            return stat.st_mtime


def get_newestfiles(path, last_check_date=0):
  # Armo una lista de todos los archivos del path indicado
  # Guardo el nombre del archivo y la fecha de creación en UTC
  files = []
  for file in os.listdir(path):
    files.append((file,creation_date(os.path.join(path, file))))

  # Retornamos una lista de archivos que han sido creados luego del último control
  return([f for f in files if f[1] > last_check_date])


path = "/etc"
last_check_date = 0
newest_file = []
time_interval = 5

while True:

  newest_file = get_newestfiles(path, last_check_date)
  if newest_file:
      last_check_date = max(newest_file,key=itemgetter(1))[1] # Me quedo con la máxima fecha de los archivos de la lista

  # Recorro los nuevos archivos e imprimo el nombre del mismo
  for f in newest_file:
    print f[0]

  # espero unos segundos para volver a verificar
  sleep( time_interval )
```