# Imprimir nombres y contenidos de varios archivos y duda sobre fecha de creación de los archivos en carpeta - Python

Tags: python, archivo, date

Después de un poco de investigación y de mucha de ayuda de las respuestas a mi pregunta anterior ( [Imprimir automáticamente cada vez que se cree un archivo en una carpeta - Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79992/imprimir-autom%C3%A1ticamente-cada-vez-que-se-cree-un-archivo-en-una-carpeta-python/80440) ), dejé el código de la siguiente manera para que sea capaz de imprimir el nombre y contenido del último archivo creado dentro de una carpeta cada 15 segundos, pero no imprimima nada si no se ha creado un nuevo archivo en la carpeta.

```
import glob    
import os      
import time

oldfile = None

while True:        
    newest = max(glob.glob('/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'), key=os.path.getctime)

    if newest == oldfile:            
        time.sleep(15)           
        continue

    oldfile = newest        
    print newest

    with open(newest) as infile:            
        print [line.strip() for line in infile]

    time.sleep(15)
```

Output

> /Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela\Prueba.txt
>   ['texto de prueba']

Hay dos problemas que no se como resolver:

- 1- ¿ Cómo hago para imprimir los nombres de varios archivos, con sus respectivos contenidos? Por ejemplo, seleccione todos los documentos (Control + E), los copie (Control + C) y cree varias copias (Control + V), que por ende se consideran archivos nuevos, pero solamente imprime uno y no varios como yo esperaba.
- 2- Cuando copio varios archivos de otras carpetas y los pego en mi carpeta donde trabaja mi código, solamente muestra el archivo con fecha de modificación mas reciente y lo ideal seria que muestre el archivo ( o los archivos) más reciente que llego a la carpeta.

Comment: Acabo de contestar tu pregunta original por si te sirve aún.

Comment: La leí y me pareció buena. Por si acaso la guarde para tenerlo como ejemplo y estudiar bien ese código. Pero por ahora necesito ver que debo añadir para que se impriman los nombres de varios archivos y su contenido   y no muestro uno solamente.

Answer (score 0):

Debes comparar no solo el último creado como haces ahora, sino que debes encontrar todos los archivos que están ahora y antes no. Tienes varias opciones:

- Creas una lista con todos los archivos presentes en tu directorio. Luego entras en el `while` y en cada iteración creas una lista con los archivos presentes y la comparas con la anterior. Imprimes los archivos diferentes y sustituyes la lista antigua por la nueva. Si quieres hacer esto lo mejor es usar conjuntos (`set`) y usar la diferencia de conjuntos:

  ```
  import time
  import glob

  RUTA = 'D:\Programacion\Python\StackOverflow\Pruebas\*'
  DELAY = 15 #en segundos

  ultimo = set(glob.iglob(RUTA))
  while True:
      actual = set(glob.iglob(RUTA))
      for file in actual - ultimo:
          with open(file,'r') as f:
              texto = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
              print(texto)

      ultimo = actual
      time.sleep(DELAY)
  ```
- También puedes comparar la fecha de la última comprobación con las de creación de tus archivos. Todo archivo que tenga una fecha superior es nuevo:

  ```
  import time
  import glob
  import os   

  RUTA = '/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'
  DELAY = 15 #en segundos

  last_time = time.time()
  while True:
      new_time = time.time()
      for file in glob.iglob(RUTA):
          if os.path.getctime(file) > last_time:
              with open(file,'r') as f:
                  texto = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
                  print(texto)

      last_time = new_time
      time.sleep(DELAY)
  ```

  Otra versión basada en la anterior sería crear una lista ordena con los archivos y su fecha de creación en tuplas. La recorremos y rompemos el ciclo en cuanto se encuentre un archivo que no sea nuevo. Esto evita recorrer siempre la lista completa:

  ```
  import time
  import glob
  import os   

  RUTA = '/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'
  DELAY = 15 #en segundos

  last_time = time.time()
  while True:
      new_time = time.time()
      files = sorted([(os.path.getctime(file),  file)
                           for file in glob.iglob(RUTA)],  reverse = True)
      for date, file in files:
          if date > last_time:
              with open(file,'r') as f:
                  texto = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
                  print(texto)
          else:
              break

      last_time = new_time
      time.sleep(DELAY)
  ```

Existen muchas formas más, la cuestión sería ver cual es la más eficiente para tu caso concreto. De todas formas, esto funciona bién para un número relativamente pequeño de archivos, si vas a tratar con un directorio con miles de archivos mejor usar las herramientas propias del sistema operativo como `FindFirstChangeNotification` (Win32 API ) o bibliotecas ya creadas con estos fines como  Watchdog.

**Nota importante:** no dices en que sistema operativo trabajas (por la ruta parece que Windows). En Linux  `getctime` no tiene porqué obtener la fecha de creación del fichero, puede ser vete a saber que (por ejemplo la fecha de la última modificación). Esto no tiene nada que ver con Python sino con el SO (ver: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_08) y con el sistema de ficheros que use. Se puede obtener la fecha real de creación pero no en todos los casos, en EXT4 si es posible pero no en otros sistemas de ficheros.